# How do I pass : as a function parameter in python?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I am working with python3 and pandas, and I would like to pass `:` as a function parameter to state all rows in a slice passed to `df.loc`.

For example, say I have a function that fills na values like so:

```
def fill_na_w_value(df, rows, columns, fill):

    for col in columns:
        df.loc[rows, columns].fillna(
            fill,
            inplace=True
        )
```

Sometimes I may not want to apply it to some rows but to apply it to **all rows**, in pandas this is accessed with `df.loc[:, col]`

If I am calling this from a function it would like

```
fill_na_w_value(df, :, ['col1'], 0)
```

But the above will give me a syntax error because of the `:`; how can I pass this as a function parameter?

Comment: `slice()` ... i think

Comment: Need `slice(None)` as `slice` requires an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slice(None)` to represent `:`. Note you can use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to pass your dataframe through a function, and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accepts a list for row and index filtering:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8, np.nan]})

def fill_na_w_value(df, row_slicer, columns, value):
    df.loc[row_slicer, columns] = df.loc[row_slicer, columns].fillna(value)
    return df

df1 = df.pipe(fill_na_w_value, slice(None), ['col1'], 0)

print(df1)

   col1
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   0.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
5   0.0
6   7.0
7   8.0
8   0.0
```

Here's an example using a `list` instead of a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object:

```
df2 = df.pipe(fill_na_w_value, [2, 5], ['col1'], 0)

print(df2)

   col1
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   0.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
5   0.0
6   7.0
7   8.0
8   NaN
```